# Inkscape - My fill tool has a stroke and I want it permanently removed

Tags: inkscape

I do not know what I did, but every time I use the fill tool in Inkscape, it sets it to a preset colour with a thick line around it. It does this every time and I want it removed for good. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Paint Bucket tool, then from the main menu select *Edit > Preferences > Tools > Paint Bucket*

Check the option "This tools own style".  This will set a default style for that tool only. You can use the currently selected object to set it to whatever you want. The tool will then always use that style. Every time you use it however, you will then need to select a fill colour.

Note that this could however quickly become annoying depending on how you use the bucket fill tool. For example, it might not be desirable if you want to fill one colour repeatedly, before moving on to another colour.  If that's the case, then you could just switch the option back to "Last Used Style".  If the stroke problem occurs again, you could just set no stroke directly after using the tool.  However if you use another tool, and then set a stroke, the tool will then remember that setting.

Note also that these options can also be set for other tools, so they can have their own style, or follow the last used fill and stroke.

Comment: Faster access to the tool settings is by double-clicking on it instead of going via menu.